# How to Convert Depth Texture Value in a Volume Shader Derived from Three.js Example?

Tags: three.js, glsl, shader, webgl

I've been extending a Three.js example on the [volume rendering example with Perlin noise](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=volume#webgl2_volume_perlin) from the official documentation.

My goal with this is to introduce an extra cube mesh into the scene and leverage a depth texture to conditionally render parts of the volume. Ideally, I aim to suppress parts of the volume whose pixel depth is greater than the corresponding value from the depth texture.

First I created a MeshDepthMaterial, and for each frame I generate the depth texture that I then feed to the volume shader.

```
depthRenderTarget = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
depthMaterial = new THREE.MeshDepthMaterial();

function animate() {

  requestAnimationFrame(animate);

  if (volumeMesh) {
    volumeMesh.visible = false;
  }

  scene.overrideMaterial = depthMaterial;

  renderer.setRenderTarget(depthRenderTarget);

  renderer.render(scene, camera);

  renderer.setRenderTarget(null);

  scene.overrideMaterial = null;

  if (volumeMesh) {
    volumeMesh.visible = true;
  }

  volumeMesh.material.uniforms.cameraPos.value.copy(camera.position);
  volumeMesh.material.uniforms.depthTexture.value = depthRenderTarget.texture;

  renderer.render(scene, camera);

}
```

And in the shader, in the marching loop, I added a check for the depth of the pixel:

```
const fragmentShader = /* glsl */ `
  ... 
  vec2 vCoords = vPos.xy;
  vCoords /= vPos.w;
  vCoords = vCoords * 0.5 + 0.5;

  vec2 uv = vCoords;
  float sceneDepth = (1.0 - texture(depthTexture, uv).r) / 0.5;
  float dist = distance(vOrigin, p);
  
  if ( dist > sceneDepth ) discard;
  if ( color.a == 0.0 ) discard;
  ...
`;
```

For a complete look at the code, here's the [JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/nge19qhc/)

My implementation does produce some desired effects, but they only seem to be accurate from specific camera angles. This inconsistency made me think that the problem might revolve around the incorrect conversion or interpretation of the depth value extracted from the depth texture within the shader.